# Compare value of an object within a dictionary value

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a dictionary object with the value being another object. 
(of string, Object)

I need to check if a value exists within the dictionary value object's property. I dont think i can use .ContainsValue as i need to compare only the property not the whole object.

Comment: depending on the number of times you do this...it might just make sense to store that as another keyed data structure...the recommendations to search the value below are O(n) which is the same algorithmic cost of building the structure itself (keeping in mind that the actual building the structure has some relative cost as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deleted answer by @koryakinp was basically correct but for language, e.g.

```
If myDictionary.Any(Function(kvp) kvp.Value.SomeProperty = someValue) Then
    'At least one item has a value where the SomeProperty property is equal to someValue.
End If
```

If you need to know how many such items there are:

```
Dim count = myDictionary.Count(Function(kvp) kvp.Value.SomeProperty = someValue)
```

Note that you can go through the `Values` collection instead, if you wish:

```
If myDictionary.Values.Any(Function(value) value.SomeProperty = someValue) Then
    'At least one item has a value where the SomeProperty property is equal to someValue.
End If

Dim count = myDictionary.Values.Count(Function(value) value.SomeProperty = someValue)
```